# Moving app data to external sd card

Tags: storage

Is it possible to move almost the total app size of an app to external sd? example 90% of its data will move to external and the 10% will stay...

I've tried moving the Clean Master app, its total size is 71 MB but only 20 MB was able to move in the external... not even 50% of total size has been moved...

Comment: The default mechanism of moving an app only moves the APK of the app. App's private data (including cache) always remains in internal storage (under /data/data).

Comment: @Firelord, wow - that's an interesting tidbit on how Android works.  I'm curious to research that more.  I always assumed an app running on SD would attempt to put all of it's other files on the SD too.  I figured that's why the SD card ends up with all those other folders I didn't create.

Comment: @Baronz You can begin from here: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/install-location.html

Comment: Please see this new article 2017/02/10 [10 most useless apps and games for Android](http://www.androidauthority.com/most-useless-apps-android-749163). Most prominent, but specifically named in the list: Clean Master (along with quote-Booster apps, Anti-Virus apps, and Task Killers-unquote)

Answer (score -1):

Easy approach: [Link2SD](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.buak.Link2SD)

Manual method:
If you are sure that the file attributes does **not** matter, then there's an acceptable way to do this. Root is required.
1. Copy the app data from `/data/data/com.example.foo` to somewhere in your SD card. Personally I recommend `sdcard/Android/data/com.example.foo`. If you are running Android Lollipop or up, there will be a symbolic link named `lib`, **leave it alone**.
2. Kill the app process. Remove the original data. Open a terminal emulator (or adb). Run

```
su
ln -s /sdcard/Android/data/com.example.foo/files /data/data/com.example.foo/files
```

That's all. To revert this job, it's a little complex. You'll have to `chmod` and `chown` the proper file modes and attributes manually after copying them back.

Special notices:
Never copy and link the `/data/data/com.example.foo` folder directly as the symbolic link `lib` inside will fail, which will lead to unknown behavior. Link every (or some of them at your choice) subfolders one by one.